# org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException with java.lang.NoSuchField exception

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have an Entity named TrainingMstr. I have removed some fields from the table and updated the entity too. But I'm still getting the following error:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------
Exception [EclipseLink-59] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The instance variable [trngRevNo] is not defined in the domain class [com.discusit.trims.entity.TrainingMstr], or it is not accessible.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: trngRevNo
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[trngRevNo-->trimsdev.trimsdev.training_mstr.trng_rev_no]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.discusit.trims.entity.TrainingMstr --> [DatabaseTable(trimsdev.trimsdev.training_mstr)])
Exception [EclipseLink-59] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The instance variable [trngRefDocNo] is not defined in the domain class [com.discusit.trims.entity.TrainingMstr], or it is not accessible.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: trngRefDocNo
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[trngRefDocNo-->trimsdev.trimsdev.training_mstr.trng_ref_doc_no]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.discusit.trims.entity.TrainingMstr --> [DatabaseTable(trimsdev.trimsdev.training_mstr)])
Exception [EclipseLink-59] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The instance variable [trngAddLinks] is not defined in the domain class [com.discusit.trims.entity.TrainingMstr], or it is not accessible.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: trngAddLinks
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[trngAddLinks-->trimsdev.trimsdev.training_mstr.trng_add_links]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.discusit.trims.entity.TrainingMstr --> [DatabaseTable(trimsdev.trimsdev.training_mstr)])
Exception [EclipseLink-59] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The instance variable [trngNxtRevDt] is not defined in the domain class [com.discusit.trims.entity.TrainingMstr], or it is not accessible.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: trngNxtRevDt
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[trngNxtRevDt-->trimsdev.trimsdev.training_mstr.trng_nxt_rev_dt]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.discusit.trims.entity.TrainingMstr --> [DatabaseTable(trimsdev.trimsdev.training_mstr)])
Exception [EclipseLink-59] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The instance variable [trngInfo] is not defined in the domain class [com.discusit.trims.entity.TrainingMstr], or it is not accessible.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: trngInfo
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[trngInfo-->trimsdev.trimsdev.training_mstr.trng_info]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.discusit.trims.entity.TrainingMstr --> [DatabaseTable(trimsdev.trimsdev.training_mstr)])
Exception [EclipseLink-59] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The instance variable [trngEffctvDt] is not defined in the domain class [com.discusit.trims.entity.TrainingMstr], or it is not accessible.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: trngEffctvDt
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[trngEffctvDt-->trimsdev.trimsdev.training_mstr.trng_effctv_dt]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.discusit.trims.entity.TrainingMstr --> [DatabaseTable(trimsdev.trimsdev.training_mstr)])
Exception [EclipseLink-59] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The instance variable [trngValidTill] is not defined in the domain class [com.discusit.trims.entity.TrainingMstr], or it is not accessible.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: trngValidTill
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[trngValidTill-->trimsdev.trimsdev.training_mstr.trng_valid_till]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.discusit.trims.entity.TrainingMstr --> [DatabaseTable(trimsdev.trimsdev.training_mstr)])
```

I have removed all the related data fields from all the SessionBeans too.

What should I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not redeployed your application correctly.  Ensure you have restarted your server and recompiled and redeployed your application.